# Captive portal with video login in wi-fi network

Tags: wifi, captive-portal

I would like to know if it's possible to make a captive portal which makes you watch a video for `x` seconds instead of a login. All the routers I've seen which support captive portals, just have the same type of login page which I can't change.

The idea is to show a webpage which shows a video, and after `x` seconds you get the internet access in the wifi network.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be achieved.
Redirect all the user traffic to 3rd party captive portal (can be an open sourced like free radius or similar) and over that portal, you can write whatever logic you want.

DaloRadius is one of the open source solution which provides similar stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The captive portal page is just a webpage.  It can do anything a webpage can, as long as the videos are hosted somewhere accessible before they get full access.  Just make the page submit a hidden login form after the video plays.